# Extracting Font 'kern' table information via fontforge and making it accessible offline for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fonts, kerning, fontforge

i had to calculate the horizontal width of a given text, using a given font including kerning information.

The glyphs name and width as well as his kerning pairs information should be accessible by the unicode value of the texts characters like this:

```
// GLYPHS[ unicode ] = [ "name", width ];
// KERNS [ unicode ] = { "nextGlyphName"        : horizontalAdjustment };
//                   = { GLYPHS[ unicode ][ 0 ] : horizontalAdjustment };
```

So, if you have a file like the following, which includes these data objects, you can copy and paste it into your sourcecode or open and import them at runtime (the first pages of a very long file per font):

```
// Family Name
// 'Times New Roman'
// EM size
// '2048'
// is_quadratic
// '1'
//
// GLYPHS[ unicode ] = [ "name", width ];
// KERNS [ unicode ] = { "nextGlyphName"        : horizontalAdjustment };
//                   = { GLYPHS[ unicode ][ 0 ] : horizontalAdjustment };
GLYPHS = {};
KERNS  = {};

GLYPHS[    32 ] = [ "space",  512 ];
KERNS [    32 ] = {
  "Upsilondieresis" :   -76,
  "Upsilon"         :   -76,
  "Tau"             :   -37,
  "Lambda"          :  -113,
  "Delta"           :  -113,
  "Alpha"           :  -113,
  "Alphatonos"      :  -113,
  "Y"               :   -76,
  "W"               :   -37,
  "V"               :   -37,
  "T"               :   -37,
  "A"               :  -113
};
GLYPHS[    33 ] = [ "exclam",  682 ];
GLYPHS[    34 ] = [ "quotedbl",  836 ];
GLYPHS[    35 ] = [ "numbersign", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    36 ] = [ "dollar", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    37 ] = [ "percent", 1706 ];
GLYPHS[    38 ] = [ "ampersand", 1593 ];
GLYPHS[    39 ] = [ "quotesingle",  369 ];
GLYPHS[    40 ] = [ "parenleft",  682 ];
GLYPHS[    41 ] = [ "parenright",  682 ];
GLYPHS[    42 ] = [ "asterisk", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    43 ] = [ "plus", 1155 ];
GLYPHS[    44 ] = [ "comma",  512 ];
GLYPHS[    45 ] = [ "hyphen",  682 ];
GLYPHS[    46 ] = [ "period",  512 ];
GLYPHS[    47 ] = [ "slash",  569 ];
GLYPHS[    48 ] = [ "zero", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    49 ] = [ "one", 1024 ];
KERNS [    49 ] = {
  "one"             :   -76
};
GLYPHS[    50 ] = [ "two", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    51 ] = [ "three", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    52 ] = [ "four", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    53 ] = [ "five", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    54 ] = [ "six", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    55 ] = [ "seven", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    56 ] = [ "eight", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    57 ] = [ "nine", 1024 ];
GLYPHS[    58 ] = [ "colon",  569 ];
GLYPHS[    59 ] = [ "semicolon",  569 ];
GLYPHS[    60 ] = [ "less", 1155 ];
GLYPHS[    61 ] = [ "equal", 1155 ];
GLYPHS[    62 ] = [ "greater", 1155 ];
GLYPHS[    63 ] = [ "question",  909 ];
GLYPHS[    64 ] = [ "at", 1886 ];
GLYPHS[    65 ] = [ "A", 1479 ];
KERNS [    65 ] = {
  "quoteright"      :  -227,
  "y"               :  -188,
  "w"               :  -188,
  "v"               :  -152,
  "Y"               :  -188,
  "W"               :  -164,
  "V"               :  -264,
  "T"               :  -227,
  "space"           :  -113
};
GLYPHS[    66 ] = [ "B", 1366 ];
GLYPHS[    67 ] = [ "C", 1366 ];
```

But please do not forget to check the existence of the special KERNS object, before you try to access it like this:

```
if ( !( KERNS[ glUnicode ] == undefined ) ) {
  if ( !( KERNS[ glUnicode ][ GLYPHS[ nextGlyphUnicode ][ 0 ] ] == undefined ) ) {
  ...
```

then you can access it like this:

```
kernWidth = KERNS[ glUnicode ][ GLYPHS[ nextGlyphUnicode ][ 0 ] ];
```

If you have the following "Text" as an example, kernWidth for the "T" (glUnicode == 84), which is followed by an "e" (nextGlyphUnicode == 101) will give you the following result:

```
kernWidth == -143
```

You can create the above mentioned file with the GLYPHS and KERNS data objects with the following script that runs fine within the `fontforge`'s "embedded" python 2.7 interpreter.
This script is designed for a windows machine, so you have to adapt your paths at first!

```
# This files name is 'Kernings.py'
# run these two commands in the fontforge "embedded" python interpreter (ffpython.exe)
# >>> script = open( "Scripts\\Kernings.py", "r" )
# >>> exec script

import fontforge

fontFilenames = [
  "arial.ttf",
  "arialbd.ttf",
  "ariali.ttf",
  "arialbi.ttf",
  "ARIALN.TTF",
  "ARIALNB.TTF",
  "ARIALNI.TTF",
  "ARIALNBI.TTF",
  "calibri.ttf",
  "calibrib.ttf",
  "calibrii.ttf",
  "calibriz.ttf",
  "cambria.ttc",
  "cambriab.ttf",
  "cambriai.ttf",
  "cambriaz.ttf",
  "times.ttf",
  "timesbd.ttf",
  "timesi.ttf",
  "timesbi.ttf",
  "verdana.ttf",
  "verdanab.ttf",
  "verdanai.ttf",
  "verdanaz.ttf"
  ]

for actFontFile in fontFilenames :
  print( "c:\\windows\\fonts\\" + actFontFile )
  out  = open( "Scripts\\Kern_" + actFontFile[ : len( actFontFile ) - 4 ] + "_json.txt", "w" )
  font = fontforge.open( "c:\\windows\\fonts\\" + actFontFile )
  out.write(
      "// Family Name\n// '"  + font.familyname          + "'\n"
    + "// EM size\n// '"      + str( font.em )           + "'\n"
    + "// is_quadratic\n// '" + str( font.is_quadratic ) + "'\n"
    + "//\n"
    + '// GLYPHS[ unicode ] = [ "name", width ];\n'
    + '// KERNS [ unicode ] = { "nextGlyphName"        : horizontalAdjustment };\n'
    + "//                   = { GLYPHS[ unicode ][ 0 ] : horizontalAdjustment };\n"
    + "GLYPHS = {};\n"
    + "KERNS  = {};\n\n"
    )
  glyphIdIterator = font.__iter__()
  for glyphName in glyphIdIterator :
    if font[ glyphName ].unicode >=0 :
      kerningStrings = []
      outstring = ( "GLYPHS[ "
        + str( font[ glyphName ].unicode ).rjust( 5 ) + " ] = [ \""
        + glyphName + "\"," 
        + str( font[ glyphName ].width ).rjust( 5 ) + " ];\n"
        )
      subs = font[ glyphName ].getPosSub("*")
      if len( subs ):
        for sub in subs:
          if len( sub ):
            for subsub in sub:
              if str( subsub ).lower().find( "'kern'" ) >=0:
                kerningStrings.append(
                  ("  \"" + str( sub[ 2 ] ) + "\"").ljust( 20 )
                + ":"     + str( sub[ 5 ] ).rjust( 6 )
                )
                break
      if ( len( kerningStrings ) ) :
        outstring = outstring + ( "KERNS [ "
          + str( font[ glyphName ].unicode ).rjust( 5 ) + " ] = {" )
        for kerningString in kerningStrings :
          outstring = outstring + "\n" + kerningString + ","
        outstring = outstring.rstrip( "," )
        outstring = outstring + "\n};\n"
      out.write( outstring )
  out.close()
  font.close()
#
# file 'Kernings.py' ends here
```

I hope, this can help.
Thank you very much for your attention,

Richard

Comment: This question should probably be broken into question and answer pair.

Comment: This code is incredible. Needed to extract kerning pairs (ASCII set only) and this helped tremendously in showing the font forge calls. Thank you so much!